# Flutter using Draggable & DragTarget: While dragging update the "childWhenDragging" location as candidate drags over a dragtarget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I've been able to get this to work while dragging a ListItem around in a ListView.  With each ListItem wrapped as a DragTarget I update attributes of the 'candidates[0]' & trigger a screen refresh.  This moves the "selected" list tile (selected via childWhenDragging) to each listtile as I pass over a dragtarget.

The goal is to drag between tabs though.  Currently I can select an item, then use another finger to switch tabs, then switch back to the original tab.  This keeps the item on the first tab selected using childWhenDragging.  However, if I switch tabs and swap with an item there, between tabs, the swap works but I am losing the childWhenDragging "selection".

This did have to add AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin to the item being dragged to keep things working between tabs... not sure why the childWhenDragging quits working when I swap with item on 2nd tab.

At the moment I'm using a single array of Items as a class { int tab, int order, Widget child } & choose what to display per tab based on the tab/order attributes.

Adding 'addAutomaticKeepAlives' to the ListViews didn't help.  Ideas?